Blue snowball microphone has a robotic sound when plugged in front USB ports on ubuntu
I recently switched from windows to ubuntu for gaming and I have had no problems so far. Steam's proton works amazingly well and the setup of ubuntu was relatively easy.
Here's my problem : I have two Blue Snowball ICE USB microphone that have a terrible robotic sound. It sounds robotic, i can't understand what i'm saying. Kind of like if the bitrate was very low, or if the mic was in slowmo. It sounds great on windows without having to tweak anything.
I've tried recording with multiple software but i always get the same sound. I tried messing with pulseaudio, alsamixer and even modifying the daemon.conf file but nothing worked. The microphone is reconised by ubuntu, sound is coming from it but it sounds real bad. Alsamixer has Front mic and Front mic boost both at approximately 50%. Ubuntu's sound settings has it on 100% and it's not muted.
Weird things happen when i record my voice into Audacity : It sounds like chiptune and the recording is very slow compared to when I listen to it. Like i can record for 10 seconds and when i play the recording it only lasts 3 seconds... Same on discord and firefox.
Thanks for reading, I hope someone will be able to help me.
Edit :
Instead of plugging my mic in the front usb ports of my pc I plugged it in one of the back usb ports and it work now !
Still my problem is not really solved. Since I use it often on different computers I would prefer to plug it in the front usb port (that works fine on windows and works on ubuntu to use a PS4 controller for example) so if anyone has an idea why it does that i'm still interested.

Well instead of plugging my mic in the front usb ports of my pc I plugged it in one of the back usb ports and it work now !
Still my problem is not really solved. Since I use it often on different computers I would prefer to plug it in the front usb port (that works fine on windows and works on ubuntu to use a PS4 controller for example) so if anyone has an idea why it does that i'm still interested.

Since you don't consider this a solution, please don't post it as an answer. Edit this information into your question instead. Since some of your computer's USB ports work and others do not, the obvious approach would be to investigate what is different between the ports. You could start with the output of lsusb when the mic is plugged into the different ports.
